# python - Generic function that accept another function as parameter and wait until condition

Tags: python, time, delegates, wait

So I have this function` that gets my user status from the database:

```
def get_status(user_name: str) -> str:
    # connect to db.
    user = ...
    return user.status
```

Now I have to wait maximum `time` until my user `status` will be `connected` (it could take up to several minutes):

```
def wait_until_user_status(user: str, timeout: int)
    status = get_status(user)
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < timeout and status != `connected`:
        time.sleep(2)
        status = get_status(user)
   if status != `connected`:
       raise Exception(f'Timeout of {timeout} seconds reached')
```

Usage:

```
try:
    wait_for('bil', 120)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

So my question is:
In case I have several function that I want to verify something inside (In the above example - user status) is it possible to declare a generic function that accepts another function and wait until timeout? (In my example - send function that return status and wait until some condition).

For example:

```
def generic_wait(timeout: int, function):
    pass
```

Usage:

```
generic_wait(timeout=120, function=wait_until_user_status(user='bil', status='connected')
```

Comment: I think you need to make `get_status` an async function. [asyncio.timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouts)

Comment: Please see my update, I would like an generic solution

Comment: My point still stands: if the `function` provided to `generic_wait` is synchronous, that means nothing else can be done while waiting for the function to finish, then how will the program check whether a timeout has occurred?

Comment: I want my function to wait this time, Nothing need to continue meanwhile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make this function generic by passing the function in arguments.
Please check the below code for better understanding.

```
def func1(arg1, arg2):
    print(f"I am {arg1} & I am {arg2}")

def call_me(func1, args):
    func1(**args)

call_me(func1, {"arg1": 10, "arg2": 20})

Output: I am 10 & I am 20
```

You can pass the function func1 with its arguments as dict inside the call_me function and unpack that with `**` into keyword arguments.